# Passing an object to a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, object

I have a project that creates an object of a class stored in a header file.
I need this object passed into a thread from the main function.

Currently I'm using `hChatThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,ChatFunc,"1",0,&dwChatThreadId);` as a way of creating a thread, and it seems I cannot change the fact that the called function can only have `LPVOID` as a type. If I could somehow change this, I could then pass the object as an argument like so: `hChatThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,ChatFunc,myObject,0,&dwChatThreadId);`

But it seems this is next to impossible.

Any ideas?

Thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI ChatFunc(LPVOID randparam)
{
    ServerMain(myObject); //need to pass object again here to be used in other functions
    return 0;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myObject w;
    w.exec();
    hChatThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,ChatFunc,"1",0,&dwChatThreadId);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can pass a pointer to the object you want to pass (make sure that the object's lifetime doesn't end before the thread ends). That's like the whole point of having a `LPVOID` parameter for the thread function.

Comment: You can cast your object type to `void*` (`LPVOID`) and cast it back in your `ChatFunc`. Another way is to make your object a singleton or accessible through a global variable. There are a few possibilities here the best one is up to you to choose.

Comment: Also relevant is `std::thread` in the `<thread>` header.

Comment: Thanks @MooingDuck I'll look at that once I get this oredeal sorted out. Looks like that could have more use to me beyond this specific problem.

Comment: As written, main() will likely exit, and so run on to its ExitProcess() call and terminate the process, before your new thread runs at all.

Comment: Note well @T.C. comment - the accepted answer below falls foul of 'make sure that the object's lifetime doesn't end before the thread ends'.

Comment: Actually, it falls foul of 'make sure that the object's lifetime doesn't end before the thread even starts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LPVOID lpParameter` to pass a pointer to the object, and then cast it back. Something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myObject w;
    w.exec();
    hChatThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,ChatFunc,&w,0,&dwChatThreadId);

    // wait for the thread to terminate,
    // otherwise w might get destroyed while the thread
    // is still using it (see comments from @MartinJames)

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ChatFunc(LPVOID param)
{
     myObject* p = static_cast<myObject*>(param);
    ServerMain(p); //need to pass object again here to be used in other functions
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out. :)
(Also, I'm gonna do a little refresher on pointers, just for the sake of it.)

Comment: Seems to work fine with `myObject* p = (myObject*)param;`, any reason for the change?

Comment: It should work either way. But in `C++`, old style `(Type*)` casting is rather deprecated. `static_cast` is more elegant (or, better to say, less ugly).

Comment: This will not work reliably.  'myObject w' will likely be destroyed by the time the thread gets the pointer to it.  You should dynamically allocate a myObject instance with new, pass the pointer to it to to CreateThread() and delete it in the thread function when it is no longer required.

Comment: ..assuming that the thread runs at all since, as written, main() can return and the process can be terminated before the new thread runs at all.

Comment: @MartinJames ... and even if the thread runs and we pass a new'ed pointer, returning from `main` while a worker thread is still running is not the best thing. It might be better just to wait till the thread finishes. I updated the answer.

Comment: @AlexD - it's not the worst, either:)

Comment: @MartinJames Agree, it is somewhere in the middle in the hierarchy of evils :).

Comment: @MartinJames, the specific object we're talking about here runs indefinitely, so there's no worry of it being destroyed (if I understood you correctly). Same with `main()`.|
I just trimmed out some of my more nasty looking code to avoid embarrassment and enable readability.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make that Object a global object in the header file, and given that you included the code:

```
#include "headerFilesName.h"
```

in the file where your main function is. Then I would declare another object inside the file with the main function and just pass it its value

```
headerFileName myNewObject;
```

with this object of the class of the header file, you should be able to access the other object you created initially.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one flexible solution - dynamically allocate 'w' with operator new, pass the pointer into CreateThread, cast it back in the thread function and, when/if the thread function exits/returns and the object instance is no longer required, delete it.

All the other solutions either don't work reliably, have messy globals or are inflexible.

Comment: If `main()` waits for the thread, allocation on the stack is still OK. Or do you classify it as inflexible? (If we continue your way, perhaps instead of `new` it should be something like `std::make_shared`.)

Comment: @AlexD You can't pass a `shared_ptr` in a `void *` (which is what `LPVOID` is).

Comment: @T.C. We could create a `shared_ptr A` in `main`, assign it to a `new`'ed `shared_ptr B`, pass _pointer_ to `B` to the thread via `void*`. Within the thread, assign `B` to thread's local `shared_ptr C` and immediately `delete B`. So lifetime of the object is controlled by `shared_ptr`s. And `new` is just a technical mean to pass `shared_ptr` to the thread.

Comment: @AlexD Or the thread could just immediately wrap the pointer it got in a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @T.C. Sure, if the object is used within the worker thread only. But I assumed (although it is nothing more than an assumption) that the object is shared between two threads. Meaning that we need to have `shared_ptr`s (or alike) which wrap the same raw pointer within the worker thread and within the main thread too. And in such case, passing a raw pointer via `void*` parameter is problematic.

Comment: Your solution may not be reliable either. The thread you are passing the pointer to may be using a different memory allocator. Any attempt to dispose the object on this thread may be undefined. Transferring ownership requires that you make the allocator accessible to the target thread.